# accumulate function in c++ malfunctioning not able to find mean

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stdvector

I need to find a number in a vector which if we take out doesn't affect the mean, I am replacing every number and finding out mean and comparing but when I try to compute mean after removing number it is always incorrect why?

mean is the original mean of the vector elements... mean1 is the new mean after removing an element but its computation is wrong every time

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) 
    {
        int n, i, sum = 0, sum1 = 0;
        cin >> n;
        vector<int> ser;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            int temp;
            cin >> temp;
            ser.push_back(temp);
        }
        int mean = accumulate(ser.begin(), ser.end(), sum) / n;

        vector<int> ser1;
        ser1 = ser;
        bool flag = false;
        vector<int>::iterator it;
        it = ser1.begin();

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            ser1.erase(it);
            int mean1 = accumulate(ser1.begin(), ser1.end(), 0) / (ser1.size());
            if (mean == mean1) 
            {
                cout << i;
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            else 
            {
                ser1 = ser;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (flag == false) {
            cout << "Impossible";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate "is wrong". What do expect in contrast to what you get. Show both with examples.

Comment: You are storing the mean in an integer variable. So it can be truncated off if the result comes as a float-number. So you are getting wrong result.

Comment: `ser1.erase(it);` invalidates `it`. So does `ser = ser1;`. So after the first time through that loop, `it` is no longer a valid iterator into `ser1` and `erase(it)` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: However, I don't get the point of this task, although it seems to show up here a lot. The only number you can remove from a sequence without changing the mean is the mean itself; that's easy to prove if it isn't obvious. But it should at least be intuitive: if you remove an above average element, you drive the average down, just as removing a below average element drives the average up. So you don't have to recalculate the mean or delete elements; just search for the mean. Am I missing some pedagogic point here?

Comment: While the behavior is **undefined** as mentioned in another comment, in practice here, you probably always try with the first item removed as you never adjust `it` in the loop. The easy fix would be something like: `ser1.erase(ser1.begin() + i);`. Also, as written, you will always get your mean rounded toward 0.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code.

In

```
 it = ser1.begin();

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            ser1.erase(it);
```

you are initalising the iterator befor the for loop. Then you call `erase`. As you can read in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase), erasing

> "Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator."

Could be even OK in your case, because you never increase the iterator. This means, you are always erasing the first element. So 2 errors. This will not work.

You are also using the wrong datatype for the mean value.

Please read also the comments under your post. Basically everything mentioned already.

I will show you additionally 2 proposals, how the code could look.

First Version checks, if reduction is possible.

2nd version does this reduction in a loop repeatedly.

Version 1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

using NumberType = int;

constexpr size_t MinNumberOfValuesToCheck = 1;
constexpr size_t MaxNumberOfValuesToCheck = 20;

int main()
{
    // Read the number of values to check
    std::cout << "How many vaues shall be checked? Please enter a number:  ";
    size_t numberOfValuesToCheck{0};
    std::cin >> numberOfValuesToCheck;
    // Limit the input to meaningful values
    numberOfValuesToCheck = std::clamp(numberOfValuesToCheck, MinNumberOfValuesToCheck, MaxNumberOfValuesToCheck);

    // Here we will store all values
    std::vector<NumberType> values(numberOfValuesToCheck);
    // Read all user input and stor it in our vector
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<NumberType>(std::cin), numberOfValuesToCheck, values.begin());

    // Calculate mean. The result is most likely a double
    double meanValue {static_cast<double>(std::accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 0)) / static_cast<double>(values.size())};
    std::cout << "\nMean value: " << meanValue << '\n';

    // Look, if there is a mean value
    std::vector<NumberType>::iterator found = std::find_if(values.begin(),values.end(),[&meanValue](NumberType& n){ return n == meanValue;});

    if (found != values.end() ) {
        std::cout << "Could erase " << *found << "New Vector:\n";
        std::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), std::ostream_iterator<NumberType>(std::cout, " "));
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "No reduction possible\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Version 2. The more "complete solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

using NumberType = int;

constexpr size_t MinNumberOfValuesToCheck = 1;
constexpr size_t MaxNumberOfValuesToCheck = 20;

int main()
{
    // Read the number of values to check
    std::cout << "How many vaues shall be checked? Please enter a number:  ";
    size_t numberOfValuesToCheck{0};
    std::cin >> numberOfValuesToCheck;
    // Limit the input to meaningful values
    numberOfValuesToCheck = std::clamp(numberOfValuesToCheck, MinNumberOfValuesToCheck, MaxNumberOfValuesToCheck);

    // Here we will store all values
    std::vector<NumberType> values(numberOfValuesToCheck);
    // Read all user input and stor it in our vector
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<NumberType>(std::cin), numberOfValuesToCheck, values.begin());

    while(numberOfValuesToCheck) {
        // Calculate mean. The result is most likely a double
        double meanValue {static_cast<double>(std::accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 0)) / static_cast<double>(values.size())};
        std::cout << "\nMean value: " << meanValue << '\n';

        values.erase(std::remove_if(values.begin(),values.end(),[&meanValue](NumberType& v){ return v == meanValue;}),values.end());

        // Check if we coud remove a value
        if (values.size() < numberOfValuesToCheck) {
            // If so then the vector has less values
            // Show some output:
            std::cout << "Could eliminate " << numberOfValuesToCheck - values.size() << " from Vector of Values. New vector:\n";
            std::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), std::ostream_iterator<NumberType>(std::cout, " "));

            // New size of vector
            numberOfValuesToCheck = values.size();
        }
        else {
            // Could not reduce more
            std::cout << "No further reduction possible\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps . . .